# how can I pass custom data my buyer input as a passthrough variable to PayPal directly?

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal-ipn, pass-through

My scenario is:
1)user input some custom data
2)he press "buy now" button,then send the custom data to PayPal.
3)After his payment,retrieve his custom data in PayPal IPN handler.

At this point,I want to pass the custom data as a pass-through variable to PayPal.

```
<input type="text" name="custom" />
```

Is it possible? Can I retrieve this value in my IPN handler?
If impossible,how can I pass custom data my buyer input as a passthrough variable to PayPal?

Welcome to anyone who have a good solution? Thanks.